# how to update "input-button" with refreshed api-element

Tags: html, angularjs, selecteditem

I'm using angularJs and my code is working fine. I get data from API, update by clicking the radio button, and put the new data back. on successful "Put" it shall get the new data and show up the new "Default" after the selected value.

to sum it up:  Everything works, but the "Default" is not on the correct selected place.

[image]

additionally here is my code:

```
<div id="container" style="width:650px">
    <ol ng-repeat="element in accountmsisdn">

        <li style=" text-align:left; float:left">
            <input name="defaultSender" type="radio"  ng-click="updateDefault(element)" ng-checked="element.default">
            <span>{{element.msisdn}} </span><span ng-if="element.default"><i>Default</i></span>
        </li>
```

and here is the JS

```
$scope.updateDefault = function(element) {
  if (AuthService.isAuth()) {

    Account.one().get().then(
      function(account) {

        account.data.defaultMsisdn = element.msisdn;
        $log.d("account: ", account.data);

        account.data.put().then(
          function(resultOk) {
            $log.d("Accountinfo ok: ", resultOk);
            $scope.user = resultOk.data;
          },
          function(resultError) {
            $log.d("Accountinfo error: ", resultError);
            ErrorService.showApiError(resultError);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you show the part of the code that sets the value of `$scope.element.default`?

Comment: Sorry..did not show up all the important html.. element is  part of the ng-repeat 
part of the json

Comment: @Flowdo: You never seem to assign `element.default`.

Comment: @ExpertSystem default is a value in the json, its either true or false
i think the problem is in the JS file, so i have to add something to the second promise.. like if(element.default===true) return "DEFAULT" ...?

Comment: @Flowdo: It is in the JSON (what JSON), but from inside the `updateDefault()` function there doesn't seem to be any line of code that either sets `element.default` to true (and unsets the previously default element) or re-assigning the whole `accountmsisdn` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `ng-repeat` needs to be at `<li>` and not at `<ol>`, and remove `float: left` from `<li>`:

```
<div id="container" style="width:650px">
    <ol>
        <li style=" text-align:left" ng-repeat="element in accountmsisdn">
            <input name="defaultSender" type="radio" ng-click="updateDefault(element)" ng-checked="element.default">
            <span>{{element.msisdn}} </span><span ng-if="element.default"><i>Default</i></span>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.updateDefault = function (element) {
    // after getting resultOk, assuming the value of default is in resultOk
    angular.forEach($scope.accountmsisdn, function (val, i) {
        val.default = false;
    });
    element.default = valueOfDefaultFromResultOk; // true/false
```

};